# flask and passenger "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: flask, passenger

I'm trying to run flask on a server with passenger. This is my passenger_wsgi.py file:

```
import sys, os
INTERP = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'flask_env', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:
    os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

from wtf import app as application

# Uncomment next two lines to enable debugging
from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
application = DebuggedApplication(application, evalex=True)
```

There is an app.py file under wtf folder. There is also `__init__.py` in there so python recognizes it as a module directory. However it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/home/hiepha19/flask_env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 88, in debug_application
app_iter = self.app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you import `app` you are importing the `app` module (which most likely has an `app` name inside it which points to your Flask app.  What you want to do is import *that* name and register it:

```
from wtf.app import app as application
# Note the extra app
```

It is worth noting that you do not need to do this manually - simply run Flask using the `run` method on the app and pass the argument `debug=True` to get the same behavior:

```
from wtf.app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```